# I'd like to define an Android TextView in XML which contains text which is a link to a URL

Tags: android, url, text, hyperlink

I'd like to define a TextView in XML which contains text which is a link to a URL. Essentially the semantics of the anchor HTML tag: `<a>`

I have been able to do most of what I want with, the `android:autoLink="web"` attribute to TextView. However, the text has to contain the URL and it is displayed to the user. I'd like to display different text which links to the URL.

Example: I can say,

```
<TextView android:text="http://foo.com" android:autoLink="web">
```

But then the user sees, "http://foo.com". I'd rather say something else, like "bar".

I tried defining the string in a string resource and using a link, such as

```
<string name="test"><a href="foo.com">bar</a></string>
```

The string shows up properly formatted, but you cannot click on it.

Comment: When using an anchor HTML tag in your strings.xml, How are you setting your textview's contents? Are you just setting the text in the xml and still using autoLink?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using HTML in strings.xml for your TextView, don't use autoLink.

Instead, in your onCreate, set the movement method to use links:

```
    TextView msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    msg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I think autoLink is for when you're dynamically setting the text.